# why it is returning two values instead of one , while using || in return statement?

Tags: javascript, function

Following is my pseudo code:

```
function main() {
    return one() || two();
}
function one() {
    console.log("one");
}
function two() {
    console.log("two");
}
main();
```

I recently studied that in the return statement if one and two functions are variables containing any values then one is returned unless it is false or null or undefined but what about while using functions in this example?
can someone help me...

Comment: What do you mean by "*returning*"?

Comment: The both functions are returning `undefined` implicitly. So, both functions will executed.

Comment: `console.log(one())` and `console.log(two())` inside the main function. You will understand what both of the function is returning.

Comment: @PM77-1 "returning" means the executed function in the return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You're not returning any values. You're writing to the console so what is returned is `undefined`
2) `undefined` is false so the `||` evaluates both sides.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of your `one()` and `two()` functions are undefined, as those are just logging the strings to the console, but not returning those.

Try this:

```js
function main() {
    return one() || two();
}
function one() {
    console.log("one");
    return "one";
}
function two() {
    console.log("two");
    return "two";
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The "value" of both the `one` and `two` function calls are the `undefined` value, because they do not return any other value.

So it would seem that you're really asking why both functions are printing to the console. This is because the act of printing to the console does not establish the "truthy" or "falsey" state of the functions. This is determined *only* by the function calls' return value, as noted above.